# Trouble with VBA checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, loops, checkbox

I am trying to create a macro that will print the selected sheets out of a workbook. The first worksheet has a set of Checkboxes that all follow the naming convention "CheckBoxX" where X is the number of that checkbox. What I'd like the code to do, is run through each of these checkboxes, see if it's checked, then select that corresponding worksheet if it is checked. However, I'm getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Here's my code:
Code:

```
Option Explicit


Sub Button14_Click()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim checkNumber As String

    For count = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.count
        checkNumber = "CheckBox" & count
        If Sheets("Print").Shapes(checkNumber).OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
            Worksheets(count + 1).Select (False)
        End If
    Next count

    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

End Sub
```

The debug always flags the line with the if statement.

I have also tried this as my if statement:

```
If Sheets("Print").Shapes(checkNumber).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then
```

---

**SOLUTION:** All I had to do was change this line:

```
If Sheets("Print").Shapes(checkNumber).OLEFormat.Object.Value = True Then
```

to this:

```
If Sheets("Print").Shapes(checkNumber).OLEFormat.Object.Object.Value = True Then
```

Comment: Are your checkboxes ActiveX-type or forms-type?

Comment: They are ActiveX

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the `ActiveX` type of checkbox (which the `OLEObject` in your code implies), you are accessing the list of `Shape` objects instead of the list of `OLEObjects`.

A quick test sub is:

```
Sub test()
    Dim mycb As Variant
    Set mycb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox1")
    Debug.Print mycb.Name
    Debug.Print mycb.Object.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need **"Checkbox 1"** rather than **"Checkbox1"**

Comment: I've tried all sorts of different spacing. Using that suggestion, I just get the error "The item with the specified name wasn't found"